# Access to the mempool

Tags: mempool, node

Is there a way to access to the mempool through RPC API? And is there a way to manipulate the mempool from the outside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view the mempool via [this RPC API endpoint](https://mainnet.tezrpc.me/chains/main/mempool/pending_operations).

You currently can't manipulate the mempool with the RPC API. You can change the mempool filter settings though (which are used to filter out operations based on min fee requirements).

Comment: RPC API endpoint link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `/chains/<chain_id>/mempool/pending_operations` is not described anywhere in the official documentation.

https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html?highlight=mempool

Comment: Indeed, certain shell RPCs are not listed there for technical reasons. However, the `mempool` RPCs are documented in the Open API spec: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/openapi.html